# PHP: is this password encryption secure?

Tags: php, password-encryption

I found this example how to hash and check the passwords with PHP. Is this secure?  Is it a good example to emulate?

```
public function hashPassword($mail, $password, $salt, $rounds='08')
{
   $length = strlen($password) * 4;
   $data = str_pad($password, $length, sha1($mail), STR_PAD_BOTH);
   $string = hash_hmac('whirlpool', $data, SERVER_KEY, true);

   return crypt($string, '$2a$' . $rounds . '$' . $salt);
}

public static function checkPassword($mail, $password, $stored)
{
   $length = strlen($password) * 4;
   $data = str_pad($password, $length, sha1($mail), STR_PAD_BOTH);
   $string = hash_hmac ('whirlpool', $data, SERVER_KEY, true);

   return (crypt($string, substr($stored, 0, 30)) === $stored);
}
```

Comment: Oooh, please don't call it decrypting passwords, you will start "the rage". Anyhow, why use anything else than bcrypt/scrypt/ppbkdf2?

Comment: okay, you're right. It isn't a decrypt function.

Comment: Actually it isn't encryption either, whirlpool is a hashing algoritm :P Now I just feel like a jerk o.O I'd still recommend a solid, proven routine like bcrypt or pbkdf2

Answer (score 2):

The hashing algorithm looks fine to me other than the fact that you are using `$2a$` instead of `$2y$`. From the [crypt() man page](http://www.php.net/crypt):

> developers targeting only PHP 5.3.7 and later should use "$2y$" in preference to "$2a$"

Also, using `08` as a cost parameter is very weak unless you're using extremely old hardware. You want to try to make it take as long as possible to hash without being an inconvenience to the user. Typically 250 ms is acceptable. On my desktop PC (which is not that modern) this equates to `11`, so with a decent server you probably want at least this much. Try playing around with that parameter until you get a number that takes around this long to calculate/verify the hash and use that.

Another fairly big concern is how you are generating the salt, but since we don't see how you do that, there isn't much that can be critiqued.

With all that said, by far the best practice is to forget about making a home brew password hashing algorithm and instead use the [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/password_hash) function built in to PHP. (For PHP < 5.5 you can download the compatibility pack from [github](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)).